# How to know that an email is real or not?

Tags: android, email

I am making an android application in which i am using a signup activity. I want to know how to check that the email that the user enters during signup is a REAL email address. I am not talking about validity. How to know it is a REAL email address or not?

Comment: Send an email to it, with instructions for the user to follow to be able to continue using your app. IOW, use the same approach that Web sites use to confirm that "the email that the user enters during signup is a REAL email address".

Comment: Use some OTP like functionality send CONFIRMATION CODE on his / her mail verify is it real email address or not.

Comment: Okay Thank you. I ll give it a try

Comment: Look into my ans I explained in detail.

Comment: I am not sure if there is an ultimate solution for this. For all the suggested solutions here, I can always bypass that by using a 10 minute mail service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check is the email address is REAL, you can use any of the below approaches.

1. Get the email address and the `Confirmation code` on email address & validate it against the generated `Confirmation code.` like the website registration confirmation.
2. Otherwise the read the device registered email Id which is real email id.
3. Best way use any social API signup using G+, Facebook,twitter,...etc any of this they will give you the valid email id.

Comment: Okay i will follow as i am told by you

Answer (score 0):

You can send a confirmation e-mail to the e-mail that the user has entered. In this mail you can give a link for the confirmed e-mails or give a confirmation code.

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching for the answer!
But as per my thinking what we should do is that:
During the sign up process is going on we should send an email to the email address and at the same time confirming whether email has been sent or not to the address.
If the email has been sent without any error then the email is valid otherwise there will be a undelivery report which will signify that the email is not valid!